# Badges that were supposed to be awarded

Tags: support, bug, badges

I have had badges in the past not get awarded to me. For example, the one that won't be awarded to me currently is the curious badge. It has that I have more than 5 positive questions asked but will not award me the badge. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Curious* badge is awarded only when two separate criteria are both met:

- Asking a question that is open, not deleted and positively scored on 5 separate days
- Having a positive question record, which is defined as:

  - (total q's - negative q's - closed q's - deleted q's)/total q's >= 0.5

Note in particular that a question that has both a negative score and is closed will count as two penalties, etc.

Source: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/89334)

Unfortunately, you don't currently have a positive question record. You've asked 19 questions, 4 of which have a negative score, 6 of which have been closed, and 3 of which have been deleted. The relevant figure is thus (19 - 4 - 6 - 3)/19 = 6/19 which is less than 0.5.

---

In general, if you feel you haven't been awarded a badge you should have been and 24 hours have elapsed (badges can take some time to be awarded), you should post here on meta so that we can look into the issue.

Comment: waiwai933 How many more questions with positive question records would I have to get?

Comment: Assuming that none of your future questions have a negative score or are closed or deleted, and that none of your current questions change their current state, you would be eligible for the Curious badge with 7 more questions.

Comment: However, you can work on getting your current questions to positive scores or being reopened by editing them to improve them. This would reduce the number of new good questions you would need to ask.

Answer (score 4):

The badges are awarded algorithmically. [As you can see](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges), the *curious* badge is fairly rare, having been awarded less than 1000 times overall. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/7867), the badge's criteria are:

## Curious

- bronze; awarded once
- Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record
- Any open question that is not deleted and has a score >= 1 is considered well-received
- Only days where all questions asked have been well-received, count (source)
- A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5.` Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!